# integrating 2 androids project into a third project

Tags: android

I am having 2 android projects.Can anyone help in integrating both these project into a single one.
Actually I am trying to operate both projects from a single page which contain an option in its user interface to run either of these projects(application).

Answer (score 0):

That should not be a problem if you declare these two applicatiosn as libraries and connect the new one to them. The final application will include both projects in its .apk file.

Here is how to set up a project as a library: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

Note that TikTakToe project in Eclipse is an example how to use libraries.